# Converting speech to text in real time using Python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I'm currently trying to create a program that will print what is being said through a microphone input into console as it is being said, rather in just one big block after the user is finished saying whatever they want to say. How would I extend the SpeechRecognition/PyAudio Modules in order to achieve this. I'm thinking it may involve being able to detect when someone has finished saying a word and then looping back around to the voice detection, but I wouldnt be sure how to implement that.

This is just the basic example I'm going off of in order to print the text after the user is finished speaking:

```
microphone = sr.Microphone(device_index=0)
r = sr.Recognizer()
with microphone as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
print(r.recognize_google(audio))
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you Nikolay! That API seems to do exactly what I'm needing for my project! :)